# Cursor above siblings

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, appkit, nsbutton

Suppose there is a window with a very simple UI hierarchy which has just two siblings: NSTextView and NSButton, and they do overlap.

My question is, why is the cursor different when hovering over the button, depending on whether there is the textview below it or not? Why is the text cursor "leaking" through the button? How do I make the button retain its cursor regardless what is beneath it?

I thought I could create an NSView, place the button inside it and somehow make the view "opaque" but I didn't get too far...

What I'm trying to do is to have a button which "floats" above the textview and still displays the proper (normal) cursor.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html

> For performance reasons, Cocoa does not enforce clipping among sibling
>   views or guarantee correct invalidation and drawing behavior when
>   sibling views overlap. If you want a view to be drawn in front of
>   another view, you should make the front view a subview (or descendant)
>   of the rear view.

You can use NSTrackingArea to update cursor manually:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html

Comment: I thought NSButton has its own tracking area. In any case, I tried to `addTrackingArea:` and it didn't work either...